# reading text from textarea in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read text from textarea when writing a webdriver test in Java. For some reason I am getting null back when I use `.getAttribute()`:

```
     WebElement text = wd.findElement(By.id("edit-pi-sample-geo-id"));

     String textagain = text.getAttribute("aaaa");
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: -1 You need to be a little bit clear while asking a question on SO.

Comment: -1 You have not posted your html at all. We should not assume that you have an element with that id with an attribute of 'aaaa'.

Comment: I just happened to be in the same situation as the OP, so I understood what he was getting at.  Some HTML would have helped indeed.  Here's the situation that the solution helped me in.  I needed to get the text I was seeing in the following textarea: 
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea Edit Control id-0-104 gwt-TextArea-readonly myreadonly" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="15" wrap="off" style="width: 280px; height: 285px; font: 8pt 'Microsoft Sans Serif',Helvetica,sans-serif; position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 305px;" readonly=""></textarea>

Comment: As you can tell in my previous comment, the text is not to be found. That's because the text is in the DOM.  I am assuming the "WebElement.getAttribute()" is accessing the DOM rather than the HTML.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I got this working. Here is the solution-

```
    WebElement text = wd.findElement(By.id("edit-pi-analytics-tms-id"));
    String textagain = text.getAttribute("value");
```

I was using the actual value in the textarea in the previous code example i posted which was kinda silly. Thanks guys for your help

Comment: Please accept your own answer to your own question, and also bear in mind you will need to access the "value" property for a variety of elements, for instance `input` elements won't have any `text` but what you see on the page will be shoved into it's `value` attribute.

Comment: The answer is the `value`as @Riv says `var x = document.getElementById('Element').value`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using selenium version 3.4 and using element.getAttribute("value") that work for me. The element.getText() would return empty value for TextArea.

Answer (score -3):

So finding an element returns a web element.  To get the text of the element you have to call getText(), so from above

```
 WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.id("edit-pi-sample-geo-id"));
 String text = element.getText()
```

Comment: Hi Robert I have tried that as well but when i use .getText() it just does not return anything

Comment: text and value are not always the same thing.

Comment: ah, right, it is a text area. you do need to get the value attribute, glad you could solve your own problem