# How to get the text from textarea of Anjular an JS element, When i tried using getText() it is returning empty text and if i used ng-model

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

Html code of Element I want to get text:

```
<textarea ng-model="event.additionalInfo" maxlength="255" rows="1" md-no-autogrow="false" md-no-resize="false" data-ng-disabled="eventNotEditable" class="ng-valid md-input ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty" id="input_30" aria-invalid="false" style=""></textarea>
```

How I'am trying:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("input_30"));
String s = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(256);
element.sendKeys(s);
Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println(element.getText());
```

If there is any best way please let me know, Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your text area is empty then how it returns the text

Comment: I feel you need to clarify your question more.  Everyone is correct though, you have no text to get with your posted example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading text from textarea in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513918/reading-text-from-textarea-in-webdriver)

Comment: Yes, Even I entered text in field it is not getting added to the HTML element,  So I'am not able to get the text back. Need to know if there is  any way deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not being clear in my Question, This Post  solved my Problem

[How to getText() from the input field of an angularjs Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564317/how-to-gettext-from-the-input-field-of-an-angularjs-application)

Actually input element contains their value in value attribute, So you should try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> values = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='controller.model.value']"));
for(WebElement el : values)
{
  String theTextIWant = el.getAttribute("value");
  System.out.println(theTextIWant);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with angular, I would suggest you to use [Protractor](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net)

To submit text in input:

```
using Protractor;

var ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
//Go to your url
ngDriver.WaitForAngular();

string s = "Test";
IWebElement query = ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("input_30"));
query.SendKeys(s);
```

to get text from input:

```
var x = ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("put the id here")).Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to use protractor, need to Discuss with our Team.

Comment: if you change ngDriver to driver than you can use it for selenium. And please accept the answer if it it was you were looking for.